# Hive - Get difference between two Hive tables based on one column

Tags: hive, outer-join, hiveql

I have two Hive tables as follows:

```
Table1:

c1 | c2 | c3
01 | june | true
02 | may | false


Table 2:

c1 | c4
01 | usa
```

I basically want to get the difference (wrt set operations context) between Table A and Table based on C1. That is, I am looking for all the rows containing c1 values that are in Table 1 but NOT in Table 2. From the above example, I need to get the second row from Table 1 as my query result.

I tried the following Hive query:

```
select c1 from table1 a left outer join table2 b

on a.c1 = b.c1 where b.c1 is null
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Column c1 Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries
```

Both Table 1 and Table 2 have their first columns named as c1. And this is something that I cannot change.

Is there something that I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining because you didn't specify the source table for `c1` in `select c1 from`. You need to specify which table you want the `c1` from since it exists in both tables. `select a.c1 from...` should give you what you want.

Comment: Ah! This is now such a silly question! However, thank you for answering it quite patiently. Appreciate it!